# Button stops working when elements are placed after it (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to make a text based idle game where multiple buttons are involved, and text around those.

Whenever I try to put text after the "Work" button it stops working, stops calling the callback on click.

I tried putting the text in a separate div, which didn't work, I also tried putting the button in its own div, which made things worse. The last thing I tried was putting the text written by the write functions (which made the formatting terrible) in a paragraph tag which somehow also didn't work.

I don't know what else to try. The only thing that doesn't seem to break it so far is putting other buttons after it.

I'm using a function to create buttons called `createButton()`, it takes in 3 arguments, the button text, the button ID, and the button callback, and to draw text I'm using a "custom" write function (details at bottom).

For the work button I'm passing in the `work()` function as the callback.

createButton function:

```
        function createButton(text, id, callback){
            // console.log(text + " " + id + " " + callback)

            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML = text; //create a button element

            //var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            gameDiv.appendChild(button); //set its parent to the game div

            button.addEventListener ("click", callback); //add the callback as a listener
        }
```

work function:

```
    function work(){
                money++;
                //TODO: find better way of updating money counter
                draw(); //redraw to update money counter
                if(stage == 1){ //increment the current stage if needed (for pacing)
                    stage = 2;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        buttonStage = 1;
                        createButton("Buy Box", "buyBox", buyBox);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
```

draw function:

```
function draw(){
                clear(); //clear the screen
                for(var i=0;i<stage;i++){
                    switch(i){
                        case 0:
                            writeln("Do this");
                            writeln(" ​|");
                            writeln(" |");
                            writeln("▼");
                            createButton("Work", "work", work); //recreating a button every second might be a problem, but i dont know how to get it to position properly otherwise
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            write("<div id=\"stage2\">");
                            writelnDiv("<br><br>Money: " + Math.round((money*100)/100), "stage2");
                            writelnDiv("", "stage2");
                            writelnDiv("Now do this", "stage2");
                            writelnDiv(" ​|", "stage2");
                            writelnDiv(" |", "stage2");
                            writelnDiv("▼", "stage2");
                            write("</div>")
                            if(buttonStage > 0){
                                createButton("Buy Box", "buyBox", buyBox);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The `write`, `writeDiv`, `writeln`, and `writelnDiv` functions both just add the text to the div's innerHTML.

All code is here: https://js.do/Grimtin10/637778

The solution is probably simple, but I don't exactly know what I'm doing with javascript.

If any more info is needed to solve this I can provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured out a solution.

Instead of using `document.createElement` I just created the button using HTML tags directly appending it to the div.

It's kind of an awful way of doing it, but it works.